# My table is too wide and is out of page

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\title{Relatório de AED}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    \input{section2}
\end{document}
```

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Método}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Melhor caso}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Pior caso}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Caso esperado}} \\ \hline
Inserir novo utilizador &
  O(1) &
  O(n) &
  O(1 + \textbackslash{}lambda) \\ \hline
Consulta dados de utilizador &
  O(1) &
  O(n) &
  O(1 + \textbackslash{}lambda) \\ \hline
Inserir contacto &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(1) = O(1)\\ Find User + Insert Contact\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(n) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find User + Insert Contact\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(log(n)) = O(log(n))\\ Find User + Insert Contact\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Remover contacto &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(1) = O(1)\\ Find user + Remove Contact\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(n) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find User + Remove Contact\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(log(n)) = O(log(n))\\ Find User + Remove Contact\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Listagem de contactos &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find User + Iterate contacts\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find User + Iterate contacts\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find User + Iterate contacts\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Inserir novo grupo &
  O(1) &
  O(n) &
  O(1 + \textbackslash{}lambda) \\ \hline
Consulta dados de grupo &
  O(1) &
  O(n) &
  O(1 + \textbackslash{}lambda) \\ \hline
Remover grupo &
  O(1) &
  O(n) &
  O(1+ \textbackslash{}lambda) \\ \hline
Inserir participante num grupo &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(1) = O(1)\\ Find Group + Insert Participant\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(n) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find Group + Insert Participant\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(log(n)) = O(log(n))\\ Find Group + Insert Participant\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Remover participante de um grupo &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(1) = O(1)\\ Find Group + Remove Participant\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(n) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find Group + Remove Participant\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(long(n)) = O(log(n))\\ Find Group + Remove Participant\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Listagem de participantes &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find Group + Iterate Participants\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(n) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find Group + Iterate Participants\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find Group + Iterate Participants\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Inserir mensagem &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(1) + (O(n) * O(1)) + (O(n) * O(1)) \\ = O(n)\\ Find User + Insert Message\\ + (Iterate Contacts * Insert Message) \\ + (Iterate Groups * Insert Message)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(n) + O(n) + (O(n) * O(n)) + (O(n) * O(n)) \\ = O(n²)\\ Find User + Insert Message\\ + (Iterate Contacts * Insert Message) \\ + (Iterate Groups * Insert Message)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(1) + (O(n) * O(1)) + (O(n) * O(1)) \\ = O(n)\\ Find User + Insert Message\\ + (Iterate Contacts * Insert Message) \\ + (Iterate Groups * Insert Message)\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Listar mensagens de contacto &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find User + Iterate messages\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(n) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find User + Iterate messages\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find User + Iterate messages\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Listar mensagens de grupo &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find Group + Iterate messages\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(n) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find Group + Iterate messages\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find Group + Iterate messages\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This goes out of the page to the right and i cant make it smalled to fit page, i tried doing tabularx but i dont know how to use it. Im new to latex

Comment: the table is oversized because of the contents in the tabulars in between which make it spread beyond page margins -- you could -- reduce font size -- apply noindent -- and apply a negative horizontal spacing to drag the table left -- have a look at the answer below

Comment: You can move the table a bit to the left by inserting `\noindent` before `\begin{tabular}`.  For more possible adjustments, it would be helpful to know the document class which specifies the basic page size.

Comment: @barbarabeeton added more code

Answer (score 6):

You should use a table to which can be prescribe a width and has column types that enables break cell contents into multiple lines. For example, `tabularx` and its `X` column type is such table:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}          % <---
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % font used in column headers
\renewcommand\theadgape{}                % reduce vertical gapes in column headers
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht] % or htp
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=0.7\hsize}L |   % make the first column narrower 
                         *{3}{>{\hsize=1.1\hsize}L | } % make other column wider
                            }
    \Xhline{1.2pt}   
\thead{Método}  & \thead{Melhor caso} & \thead{Pior caso} & \thead{Caso esperado}   \\ 
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
Inserir novo utilizador 
    &   O(1)    &   O(n)    & O(1 + \textbackslash{}lambda)                         \\ 
    \hline
Consulta dados de utilizador 
    &   O(1)    &   O(n)    & O(1 + \textbackslash{}lambda)                         \\ \hline
Inserir contacto 
    &   O(1) + O(1) = O(1) Find User + Insert Contact
        &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n)  Find User + Insert Contact
            &   O(1) + O(log(n)) = O(log(n)) Find User + Insert Contact             \\ \hline
Remover contacto 
    &   O(1) + O(1) = O(1) Find user + Remove Contact
        &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) Find User + Remove Contact
            &    O(1) + O(log(n)) = O(log(n)) Find User + Remove Contact            \\ \hline
Listagem de contactos 
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) Find User + Iterate contacts
        &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) Find User + Iterate contacts
            &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) Find User + Iterate contacts                     \\ \hline
Inserir novo grupo 
    &   O(1)    &   O(n)    &   O(1 + \textbackslash{}lambda)                       \\ \hline
Consulta dados de grupo 
    &   O(1)    &   O(n)    &   O(1 + \textbackslash{}lambda)                       \\ \hline
Remover grupo 
    &   O(1)    &   O(n)    &   O(1+ \textbackslash{}lambda)                        \\ \hline
Inserir participante num grupo 
    &   O(1) + O(1) = O(1) Find Group + Insert Participant 
        &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) Find Group + Insert Participant
            &   O(1) + O(log(n)) = O(log(n)) Find Group + Insert Participant        \\ \hline
Remover participante de um grupo 
    &   O(1) + O(1) = O(1) Find Group + Remove Participant
        &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) Find Group + Remove Participant
            &   O(1) + O(log(n)) = O(log(n)) Find Group + Remove Participant        \\ \hline
Listagem de participantes 
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) Find Group + Iterate Participants
        &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) Find Group + Iterate Participants
            &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) Find Group + Iterate Participants                \\ \hline
Inserir mensagem 
    &   O(1) + O(1) + (O(n) * O(1)) + (O(n) * O(1)) 
        = O(n) Find User + Insert Message  + (Iterate Contacts * Insert Message) 
        + (Iterate Groups * Insert Message)
        &   O(n) + O(n) + (O(n) * O(n)) + (O(n) * O(n))
            = O(n²) Find User + Insert Message + (Iterate Contacts * Insert Message) 
            + (Iterate Groups * Insert Message)
                &   O(1) + O(1) + (O(n) * O(1)) + (O(n) * O(1))
                    = O(n) Find User + Insert Message
                    + (Iterate Contacts * Insert Message)
                    + (Iterate Groups * Insert Message)                             \\ \hline
Listar mensagens de contacto 
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) Find User + Iterate messages
        &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) Find User + Iterate messages
            &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) Find User + Iterate messages                     \\ \hline
Listar mensagens de grupo 
    & O(1) + O(n) = O(n) Find Group + Iterate messages
        &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) Find Group + Iterate messages
            &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) Find Group + Iterate messages                    \\ 
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, all inserted `tabular`s are removed, consequently the table's  code is significant shorter and clearer. `Xhline` is defined in the `makecell` package, which also define `\thead` command as well `\makegapedcells` macro that add vertical space determined by `\setcellgapes` around cells' contents.

[image]

**Addendum:**
A combination of my original answer and idea from @{Mico answer (moving common text from right three columns into the first). Cells are still in jail of vertical and horizontal lines:-)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,
            makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|
    >{\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}L{1.6}|       % that this work, you need to use `linbreak`!
                         *{3}{>{$}L{0.8}<{$}| }
                            }
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\thead{Método}  
    &   \text{\thead{Melhor caso}} 
        &   \text{\thead{Pior caso}} 
            &   \text{\thead{Caso esperado}}            \\ 
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
Inserir novo utilizador 
    &   O(1)    &   O(n)    & O(1 + \lambda)        \\ \hline
Consulta dados de utilizador\linebreak
\emph{Find User + Insert Contact}
    &   O(1)    &   O(n)    & O(1 + \lambda)        \\ \hline
Inserir contacto\linebreak
\emph{Find User + Insert Contact}
    &   O(1) + O(1) = O(1) 
        &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n)  
            &   O(1) + O(\log(n)) = O(\log(n))      \\ \hline
Remover contacto\linebreak
\emph{Find user + Remove Contact}
    &   O(1) + O(1) = O(1) 
        &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
            &    O(1) + O(\log(n)) = O(\log(n))     \\ \hline
Listagem de contactos\linebreak
\emph{Find User + Iterate contacts} 
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) 
        &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) 
            &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n)                  \\ \hline
Inserir novo grupo 
    &   O(1)    &   O(n)    &   O(1 + \lambda)      \\ \hline
Consulta dados de grupo 
    &   O(1)    &   O(n)    &   O(1 + \lambda)      \\ \hline
Remover grupo 
    &   O(1)    &   O(n)    &   O(1+ \lambda)       \\ \hline
Inserir participante num grupo\linebreak
\emph{Find Group + Insert Participant} 
    &   O(1) + O(1) = O(1) 
        &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n)  
            &   O(1) + O(\log(n)) = O(\log(n))      \\ \hline
Remover participante de um grupo\linebreak
\emph{Find Group + Remove Participant}
    &   O(1) + O(1) = O(1) 
        &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n)  
            &   O(1) + O(\log(n)) = O(\log(n))      \\ \hline
Listagem de participantes\linebreak
\emph{Find Group + Iterate Participants}
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) 
        &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n)  
            &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n)                  \\ \hline
Inserir mensagem\linebreak
\emph{Find User + Insert Message  + (Iterate Contacts * Insert Message) + (Iterate Groups * Insert Message)}
    &   O(1) + O(1) + (O(n)\cdot O(1)) + (O(n)\cdot O(1)) = O(n)  
        &   O(n) + O(n) + (O(n)\cdot O(n)) + (O(n)\cdot O(n)) = O(n²) 
                &   O(1) + O(1) + (O(n)\cdot O(1)) + (O(n)\cdot O(1)) 
                                                    \\ \hline
Listar mensagens de contacto\linebreak
\emph{Find User + Iterate messages}
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) 
        &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
            &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n)                  \\ \hline
Listar mensagens de grupo\linebreak
\emph{Find Group + Iterate messages}
    & O(1) + O(n) = O(n) 
        &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
            &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n)                  \\ 
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's another `tabularx`-based solution. It moves material that occurs repeatedly in columns 2, 3, and 4 into colunmn 1; the first column is made wider than the other three. It also employs math mode automatically in the three data columns.

The solution also strives to create a more open "look", by removing all vertical lines and using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines. Hopefully, your readers will reward your effort by lingering longer over the table and actually absorbing the information you wish to provide.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} 
      >{\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}L{1.36} % automatic hanging indentation
      *{3}{>{$}L{0.88}<{$}}                 % automatic math mode
      @{}} % Note: 1.36 + 3*0.88 = 4 = number of X-type columns
\toprule  
Método & \mbox{Melhor caso} & \mbox{Pior caso} & \mbox{Caso esperado} \\
\midrule
Inserir novo utilizador nes
    &   O(1)    & O(n)    & O(1 + \lambda)        \\ \addlinespace
Consulta dados de utilizador 
    &   O(1)    & O(n)    & O(1 + \lambda)        \\ \addlinespace
Inserir contacto. 
\linebreak Find User + Insert Contact
    &   O(1) + O(1) = O(1) 
    &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(\log(n)) \allowbreak= O(\log(n)) \\ \addlinespace
Remover contacto.
\linebreak Find User + Remove Contact
    &   O(1) + O(1) = O(1) 
    &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(\log(n)) \allowbreak= O(\log(n)) \\ \addlinespace
Listagem de contactos.
\linebreak Find User + Iterate contacts
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n)                        \\ \addlinespace
Inserir novo grupo 
    &   O(1)    & O(n)    &   O(1 + \lambda)      \\ \addlinespace
Consulta dados de grupo 
    &   O(1)    & O(n)    &   O(1 + \lambda)      \\ \addlinespace
Remover grupo 
    &   O(1)    & O(n)    &   O(1 + \lambda)      \\ \addlinespace
Inserir participante num grupo.
\linebreak Find Group + Insert Participant
    &   O(1) + O(1) = O(1)  
    &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(\log(n)) \allowbreak= O(\log(n)) \\ \addlinespace
Remover participante de um grupo.
\linebreak Find Group + Remove Participant
    &   O(1) + O(1) = O(1) 
    &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(\log(n)) \allowbreak= O(\log(n)) \\ \addlinespace
Listagem de participantes. 
\linebreak Find Group + Iterate Participants
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n)                        \\ \addlinespace
Inserir mensagem. 
\linebreak Find User + Insert Message  + (Iterate Contacts * Insert Message) 
           + (Iterate Groups * Insert Message)
    &   O(1) + O(1) + (O(n) \cdot O(1)) + (O(n) \cdot O(1)) \allowbreak= O(n)        
    &   O(n) + O(n) + (O(n) \cdot O(n)) + (O(n) \cdot O(n)) \allowbreak= O(n^2) 
    &   O(1) + O(1) + (O(n) \cdot O(1)) + (O(n) \cdot O(1)) \allowbreak= O(n)  \\ \addlinespace
Listar mensagens de contacto. 
\linebreak Find User + Iterate messages
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n)                        \\ \addlinespace
Listar mensagens de grupo. 
\linebreak Find Group + Iterate messages
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n)                        \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You also reorganise table! Only now did I notice that the text below equation is repeat in each of last three cells in row. nice answer! (+1 of course)

Comment: @Zarko - Many thanks for the compliment! :-) I've upvoted your answer too, BTW.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another alternative:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\qquad\quad}*{3}{>{$}L<{$}}@{}}
\toprule  
 \mbox{Melhor caso} & \mbox{Pior caso} & \mbox{Caso esperado} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Inserir novo utilizador nes}\\
       O(1)    & O(n)    & O(1 + \lambda)        \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Consulta dados de utilizador}\\
       O(1)    & O(n)    & O(1 + \lambda)        \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Inserir contacto. (FU + IC)}\\ 
       O(1) + O(1) = O(1) 
       & O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
       & O(1) + O(\log(n)) \allowbreak= O(\log(n)) \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Remover contacto. (FU + RC)}\\
       O(1) + O(1) = O(1) 
    &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(\log(n)) \allowbreak= O(\log(n)) \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Listagem de contactos. (FU + ItC)}\\
       O(1) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n)                        \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Inserir novo grupo}\\ 
       O(1)    & O(n)    &   O(1 + \lambda)      \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Consulta dados de grupo}\\ 
       O(1)    & O(n)    &   O(1 + \lambda)      \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Remover grupo}\\ 
       O(1)    & O(n)    &   O(1 + \lambda)      \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Inserir participante num grupo. (FG + IP)}\\
       O(1) + O(1) = O(1)  
    &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(\log(n)) \allowbreak= O(\log(n)) \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Remover participante de um grupo. (FG + RP)}\\
       O(1) + O(1) = O(1) 
    &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(\log(n)) \allowbreak= O(\log(n)) \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Listagem de participantes. (FG + ItP)}\\ 
       O(1) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n)                        \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Inserir mensagem. (FU + IM  + (ItC * IM) + (ItG * IM))}\\ 
       O(1) + O(1) + (O(n) \cdot O(1)) + (O(n) \cdot O(1)) \allowbreak= O(n)        
    &   O(n) + O(n) + (O(n) \cdot O(n)) + (O(n) \cdot O(n)) \allowbreak= O(n^2) 
    &   O(1) + O(1) + (O(n) \cdot O(1)) + (O(n) \cdot O(1)) \allowbreak= O(n)  \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Listar mensagens de contacto. (FU + ItM)}\\ 
       O(1) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n)                        \\ \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Listar mensagens de grupo. (FG + ItM)}\\ 
       O(1) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(n) + O(n) = O(n) 
    &   O(1) + O(n) = O(n)                        \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\smallskip

FU = Find User, IC = Insert Contact, RC = Remove Contact, ItC = Iterate Contacts, FG = Find Group, IP = Insert Participant, RP = Remove Participant, ItP = Iterate Participants, IM = Insert Message, ItG = Iterate Groups, ItM = Iterate Messages 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico: Thanks. I didn't even notice this typo.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \begin{document}
    \footnotesize \noindent\hspace{-2cm}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Método}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Melhor caso}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Pior caso}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Caso esperado}} \\ \hline
        Inserir novo utilizador &
        O(1) &
        O(n) &
        O(1 + \textbackslash{}lambda) \\ \hline
        Consulta dados de utilizador &
        O(1) &
        O(n) &
        O(1 + \textbackslash{}lambda) \\ \hline
        Inserir contacto &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(1) = O(1)\\ Find User + Insert Contact\end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(n) + O(n) = O(n)\\ Find User + Insert Contact\end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}O(1) + O(log(n)) = O(log(n))\\ Find User + Insert Contact\end{tabular} \\ \hline

        Inserir novo grupo &
        O(1) &
        O(n) &
        O(1 + \textbackslash{}lambda) \\ \hline
        Consulta dados de grupo &
        O(1) &
        O(n) &
        O(1 + \textbackslash{}lambda) \\ \hline
        Remover grupo &
        O(1) &
        O(n) &
        O(1+ \textbackslash{}lambda) \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```